# Connecting from incoming international to domestic flight at LAX, where will I pass immigration?

Tags: layovers, american-airlines, lax

I'm connecting from an incoming international flight (Hong Kong - LA) to a domestic flight (LA - Austin) at LAX. Both flights are with American Airlines, booked under one ticket. I have a 2 hour layover, and I have Global Entry.

Will I pass through immigration and customs at LA or Austin? Will I need to check out my luggage at LAX and check them back in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will pass customs in Los Angeles. In the US, you always pass customs at your port of entry.

You will pick up your luggage, pass customs and immediately deposit it again at a specialized luggage transit counter.

Likewise, you will pass immigration in LA as well.

Comment: "In the US, you always pass customs at your port of entry." Note that the port of entry may or may not be in the US. If flying directly to the US from an airport with preclearance facilities, your port of entry is probably there. In this case, Hong Kong has no US preclarance facilities.